# 非同期処理で値が保持されない

Tags: c++, 非同期

現在、C++でRESTサーバを作成するのに以下のPistacheというOSSを利用しています。
https://github.com/oktal/pistache

リクエストを受け付けると、画像をBase64に変換してJSONで応答したいと考え、以下を実装しました。
期待するレスポンスは以下の通りです。
itr->firstで キーを設定します。
{
  "camera_1": base64でエンコードされた値,
  "camera_2": base64でエンコードされた値
}

しかし、itr->first は空になっており期待する結果となりません。これは、非同期のコールバックの処理が行われる頃にはitrは既に最後まで走査が終わってしまい、対応したitrの値を取得することが出来ないのだろうと想像していますが、具体的にどのように解決すればよいのか分かりません。教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```
void ApiImpl::get_camera_image(Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter &response)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> request_url{
        {"camera_1", "http://via.placeholder.com/600"},
        {"camera_2", "http://via.placeholder.com/300"}};

    std::vector<Async::Promise<Http::Response>> responses;

    std::string responce_body = "";
    nlohmann::json json_response;
    std::string base64;

    /* 全てのキーと値の走査 */
    for (auto itr = request_url.begin(); itr != request_url.end(); itr++)
    {
        auto resp = client->get(itr->second).send();
        resp.then(
            [&](Http::Response result) {
                responce_body = result.body();
                std::cout  << itr->first << std::endl;  /* 非同期処理のコールバック中で itr->first が空になっている */
                base64 = Base64::Encode(result.body());
                json_response[key] = base64;
            },
            [](exception_ptr &ptr) { std::cout << "An exception occured during user retrieval:" << std::endl; });

        /* 非同期のリクエストをPromiseの配列に追加 */
        responses.push_back(std::move(resp));
    }

    /* awaitに非同期のリクエストを登録する */
    auto sync = Async::whenAll(responses.begin(), responses.end());

    /* 以下はサンプルコードを参考にしたため完全に理解できていませんが、全部のPromiseの応答であるFutureを最大5秒待つと想定  */
    Async::Barrier<std::vector<Http::Response>> barrier(sync);
    barrier.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    auto json_base64 = json_response.dump();
    response.headers().add<Pistache::Http::Header::ContentType>(MIME(Application, Json));
    response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, json_base64);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            [&](Http::Response result) {
```

となっていて、[ラムダ式は参照によって暗黙にキャプチャ](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture)します。しかしキャプチャしたはずの`itr`は`for`ループを抜けた時点で破棄済みなので正しくアクセスできません。`[=]`を使ってコピーを取得してはどうでしょうか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。[&,itr](Http::Response result) とすることで、期待する動作となりました。[=]だとビルドが通りませんでしたが、itrのみコピーキャプチャーにすることでうまく動作しました。全く違う方方向に向かいそうだったので非常に助かりました。

Comment: @mentai 質問文に現れていない`key`をキャプチャしたりしていてコードは提示できませんでした。安全のためキャプチャしたい変数を個別に明示することをお勧めします。